# Dataset of diesel consumption by US state and year

Tags: data-request, usa, transportation

Need a dataset, for diesel consumption by US state and by year, going back to 1990 if possible.

Comment: I guess you mean for human transport? With or without agriculture and maritime shipping?

Comment: [This question needs lot more information](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like).

Answer (score 1):

Not per state, but here's the US consumption with various categories (on-highway, farm, etc)

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Historical-diesel-consumption-in-the-United-States-Farm-includes-agricultural-diesel_fig1_317730686

[image]

source:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317730686_Trends_and_Hybridization_Factor_for_Heavy-Duty_Working_Vehicles